# Why is a subsequence defined that way?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading a book (Analysis I by Terence Tao), where the author introduces the definition of a subsequence:

> **Definition** (Subsequences). Let $(a_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ an $(b_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ be sequences of real numbers. We say that $(b_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of $(a_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ if and only if there exists a strictly increasing function $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ (i.e., $f(n+1) > f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$) such that
> $$b_n = a_{f(n)}, \text{for all $n \in \mathbb N$}$$

Consider two sequences $(2n)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ and $(2n-2)_{i=1}^{\infty}$. One can quickly see that both sequences correspond to the sequence

$$0,2,4,6,8,10\cdots$$

However, $(2n)_{i=0}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of $(n)_{i=0}^{\infty}$, but $(2n-2)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is not (because $0 \in \mathbb N$, but the $(2n-2)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ doesn't have an element with index $0$) . In fact, if we use the aforementioned definition of subsequences, *any* sequence with a starting index larger than $0$ (i.e., any sequence $(a_i)_{i=m}^{\infty}$ where $m ≥ 1$) can't be a subsequence of any sequence (including itself).

And thus my question is, why do we need to define the subsequences the way it defined above, instead of using this alternative (which seemingly rectifies the inconsistencies I've mentioned above, while preserving all the other properties):

> **Alternative definition**. Let $(a_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ an $(b_{i})_{i=m}^{\infty}$ be sequences of real numbers. We say that $(b_{i})_{i=m}^{\infty}$ is a subsequence of $(a_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ if and only if there exists a strictly increasing function $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb N$ (where $A = \{n \in \mathbb N \mid n ≥ m \text{ for some natural number $m$}\}$) such that
> $$b_n = a_{f(n)}, \text{for all $n \in A$}$$

Is there a problem with the alternative definition?

Comment: Fundamentally something like that would be fine, but in abstract contexts it's easier to just standardize your indexing scheme to be only 0-based or only 1-based. Then you can just generally acknowledge that your theorems don't depend on the indexing scheme so as to allow for other indexing schemes in applications of your theorems. But as for technicalities, your $b_i$ should now start at $m$, not $0$. It would be weird to have $b_i$ for $i=0,1,\dots,m-1$ just be "whatever" and then suddenly contain elements of $a_i$ once $i \geq m$.

Comment: @Ian, True, $b_i$ should start at $m$, $0$ was a typo. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, a sequence can start at any integer you want. But usually the reason to not have it start at $0$ or $1$ is to avoid shifting around somewhere else in the notation. For a possibly familiar example from calculus, you may have encountered $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ since $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ doesn't make sense when $n=0$ or $n=1$. You could describe what is "really" the same series as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n+2)}$ but that $n+2$ is clunky and so we resist writing it.

Outside of such contexts with particular sequences, it's easier to standardize your indexing scheme to be either $0$-based or $1$-based. Any reasonable theorem you might prove with this setup can always be adapted to deal with sequences that start somewhere else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work ultraformally, a sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R},$ and so you cannot just start indexing at 1--you have a new object, not a sequence. Your alternative definition is too broad, since it captures a notion of "eventual" subsequences, which is a different concept. Also, it doesn't apply to the case you have, since it is again defined for two sequences starting at 0, not for two generic sequences.

In everyday life, nobody will be formal enough to tell you that $(2n-2)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(2n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are different types of objects, although if you go down to details they are.

Comment: It wasn't defined for two sequences starting at $0$. I meant to write $(b_{i})_{i=m}^{\infty}$ instead of $(b_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$. Sorry!

Comment: In my textbook a sequence was defined as a function $f: \{n \in \mathbb Z \mid n ≥ m\} \rightarrow \mathbb R$, not as $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ though.

Comment: @IlyaStokolos That's true (I just checked). This is a delicate matter of choosing notation to avoid things being cumbersome while not constraining generality too much. In principle, a completely generic subsequence could be defined so that $b_n$ starts at $m$ and $b_n=a_{f(n)}$ for all $m \geq 1$ where $f$ is any strictly increasing function $f$ whose domain contains $\{ m,m+1,\dots \}$ and whose range is contained in the domain of $a$. But you can always fuss about with indices to get things to match the notation of the definition in the OP.

Comment: Typo, $m \geq 1$ was supposed to be $n \geq m$.

Comment: @Ian True, my main problem with the initial definition of a subsequence was that the definition seemed to be too restrictive (i.e., applying only to the subsequences starting from the index $0$). But if I understood you correctly, using generic definition of a subsequence unnecessarily complicates things (i.e., the proofs become more verbose), while at the end all important theorems apply to any sequence (that is, the starting index is not important). I guess I get it now. You should consider converting your comments into an answer! I will gladly accept it.